# Yii controller action without view

Tags: php, curl, yii, yii-extensions

I have the following method in my controller named HelloController that does not have any view:

```
public function actionGetContent(){
      $output = Yii::app()->curl->get('http://www.example.com',array());
      echo $output;
}
```

The line below takes the content from the site : 'http://www.example.com' using curl

```
Yii::app()->curl->get(websiteurl)
```

I tried this:

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $this->createUrl('/work/15/Hello/GetContent');?>"></iframe>
```

The url is such because, the HelloController is placed in the modules of the protected folder. I have successfully created the routing rules, thus the problem is not pertaining to routing.

Can someone suggest me a way where I can put the contents i get from the above controller to the iframe in a yii controller that does not have a view page?

Comment: why dont you directly add the 'http://www.example.com' in your iFrame src rather making controller ?

Comment: @zzlalani: I am doing this because I have a logic to add in the controller. Its a MVC framework for your info. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to get the final iframe src url, and try to open the url in your browser to see whether it's correct?

Comment: Your suggestions worked. It is a URL problem so the credit goes to you.

Answer (score 1):

You should also don't forget to use

```
Yii::app()->end();
```